# How to prevent wordpress authors from inserting html in posts and pages

Tags: wordpress

The wordpress page/post editor enables the authors to insert html in the **"html" tab**. Some authors may insert ads or other stuff and make the pages cluttersome. I want to disable tags like `<script>,<meta>,iframe` etc. but want them to insert things like images and embed videos.

Is there a way to do this in wordpress 3.3.1 without removing the **"html" tab** of the editor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could strip this data when the content is displayed like so

```
add_filter('the_content', 'clean_post');

function clean_post($data) {
    return strip_tags($content, '<p><a><ul><li><img><video>');
}
```

The string pass into strip_tags as the second parameter is the list of tags you want to allow.

You can also do this before a post is saved. I think the filter is `content_save_pre` but don't recall off hand. I prefer to save user data as it's entered and clean it up on output.